# Utility for Python date ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, design-patterns

I'm trying to write something that can take a description and a date range and return all the dates that satisfy that description.

Descriptions can be anything from the following...

```py
parsed_tests_dict = [
    {"Saturday": [5]},
    {"Sunday": [6]},
    {"Weekend": [5, 6]},
    {"Weekday": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"Monday-Saturday": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]},
    {"Jan": "", "Feb": "", "Mar": "", "Nov": "", "Dec": ""},
    {"Jan-Feb": "", "Jan-Mar": "", "Jan-Apr":"", "Mar-Oct": "Apr-Oct", "May-Oct": "",
     "Jul-Nov": "", "Nov-Feb": "", "Nov-Mar": "", "Nov-Dec": "", "Dec-Jun": ""}
```

So we could have a situation whereby Monday-Saturday appears, so the utility would bucket all the dates within the date range that fall between `Monday-Saturday` and then another bucket for all the dates that are `Sunday`.

Now there can also be a situation whereby, we need to bucket `Jan-Mar`, `Apr-Oct`, `Nov-Dec` AND `Weekends` - in this scenario, we would go through say 1-year date range, bucket every weekday that is between `Jan-Mar`, `Apr-Oct` and `Nov-Dec` and finally, all the `Weekends` in between would be bucketed under `Weekends`

I want to try to be as efficient and fast as possible and have been trying a method of this structure:

```py
STR2WKDAY = {
        'mon': 0, 'tue': 1, 'wed': 2, 'thu': 3, 'fri': 4, 'sat': 5, 'sun': 6,
        'wkd': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'wke': [5, 6], 'all': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
}
STR2MON = {
        'jan': 1, 'feb': 2, 'mar': 3, 'apr': 4, 'may': 5, 'jun': 6,
        'jul': 7, 'aug': 8, 'sep': 9, 'oct': 10, 'nov': 11, 'dec': 12,
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I would be interested to see other solutions to this problem as mine feels a bit 'wrong' -

```
class DateRange(Database):

    parsed_dates = []

    def __init__(self, days, weekdays, months):
        super().__init__()
        self.days = str(days)
        self.weekdays = frozenset(DateRange.flatn(weekdays))  # flat set of ints
        self.months = frozenset(DateRange.flatn(months))  # flat set of ints

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.days

    def accepts(self, dt):
        return any([
            dt.weekday() in self.weekdays,
            dt.month in self.months,
        ])

    @staticmethod
    def get_days(description):
        for days in description:
            wkdays = list()
            months = list()
            for item in days:
                item = item.strip().lower().replace('ee', '', 1)  # weekend,weekday => wke,wkd
                if '-' not in item:
                    if item[:3] in Constants.STR2WKDAY:
                        wkdays.append(Constants.STR2WKDAY[item[:3]])
                    elif item[:3] in Constants.STR2MON:
                        months.append(Constants.STR2MON[item[:3]])
                else:
                    f, t = item.split('-', 2)
                    f = f.strip()
                    t = t.strip()
                    if f[:3] in Constants.STR2WKDAY:
                        f = Constants.STR2WKDAY[f[:3]]
                        t = Constants.STR2WKDAY[t[:3]]
                        if f > t:
                            wkdays.append([i for i in range(t + 1)])
                            wkdays.append([i for i in range(f, 7)])
                        else:
                            wkdays.append([i for i in range(f, t + 1)])
                    elif f[:3] in Constants.STR2MON and t[:3] in Constants.STR2MON:
                        f = Constants.STR2MON[f[:3]]
                        t = Constants.STR2MON[t[:3]]
                        if f > t:
                            months.append([i for i in range(t + 1)])
                            months.append([i for i in range(f, 13)])
                        else:
                            months.append([i for i in range(f, t + 1)])

            DateRange.parsed_dates.append(DateRange(days[0], wkdays, months))

    @staticmethod
    def flatn(array):
        if isinstance(array, list):
            for element in array:
                yield from DateRange.flatn(element)
        else:
            yield (array)

    @staticmethod
    def date_range(from_date, to_date):
        for n in range((to_date - from_date).days + 1):
            yield from_date + timedelta(n)
```

Then calling this I just pass a Numpy array of descriptions atm to `get_days()` - I.E:

`[['Saturdays'], ['Sundays'], ['Weekdays']]`

This will then bucket every date that falls into each description. - This is long, so thanks to anyone who has a go and I appreciate any advice as I'm fairly new to programming.

### Example usage

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from collections import defaultdict


class Constants:
    STR2WKDAY = {
        'mon': 0, 'tue': 1, 'wed': 2, 'thu': 3, 'fri': 4, 'sat': 5, 'sun': 6,
        'wkd': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'wke': [5, 6], 'all': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    }
    STR2MON = {
        'jan': 1, 'feb': 2, 'mar': 3, 'apr': 4, 'may': 5, 'jun': 6,
        'jul': 7, 'aug': 8, 'sep': 9, 'oct': 10, 'nov': 11, 'dec': 12,
    }


def usage(start_date, end_date, description):
    active_dates_dict = defaultdict(list)
    # populate the list in DateRange with dates that match the description for given date range
    DateRange.active_days(description)
    for date in DateRange.parsed_dates:
        # iterate over the dates and organise them into buckets that match the description
        for dt in [dt for dt in DateRange.date_range(datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
                                                     datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date())
                   if date.accepts(dt)]:
            # add the datetime objects to a list of values with the description as the key
            active_dates_dict[str(date)].append(str(dt.isoformat()))

    return active_dates_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = usage(start_date="2020-01-01", end_date="2020-01-04", description=[['Monday-Saturday']])
    print(a)

    '''

    Possible descriptions - it's worth noting that you can have more than one of these descriptions at the same time 

    i.e     we could have Nov-Dec AND Weekend so we would need to bucket all dates that are from Nov-Dec that are also no weekends 
            and then the remaining dates would do in the Weekend bucket 

      Saturday
      Sunday
      Weekend
      Weekday
      Monday-Saturday
      Jan  
      Feb
      Mar
      Nov
      Dec
      Jan-Feb 
      Jan-Mar
      Jan-Apr
      Mar-Oct 
      Apr-Oct
      May-Oct
      Jul-Nov
      Nov-Feb
      Nov-Mar
      Nov-Dec
      Dec-Jun

      Not supported yet (Not sure how) - nice to have but not a Must have 

      3rd Nov - Dec
      9th Mar - 2nd Nov
      Jan-8th Mar
      3rd Nov-8th Mar
    '''
```

Any improvements are appreciated

Comment: What is the `Database` in `class DateRange(Database)`? Is it your custom class too, or provided by an external library? Can I get it from somewhere to run the code locally?

Comment: @Bob your recent edits (e.g. [today](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/129046), [yesterday](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/129017))have been rejected because we cannot assume you have the same identity as the OP. If that is the case please click the “contact [us]” link at the bottom of the page and use to form to request an account merge.

Answer (score 1):

The pandas library has various [functions for creating, manipulating and selecting date ranges](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html).  For example, `date_range(start, stop)` creates a range of dates.  `bdate_range(start, stop, ...)` can take a mask to only create certain days of the week, and can skip holidays.

One way to create your example date range:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.bdate_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-01-04", freq='C', weekmask='Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')
```

Another method might be to create the dates and then select the dates matching the description.  Something like:

```
# create a range of dates
a = pd.date_range(start="2020-01-01", end="2020-12-31")

# select dates according to a description
weekday = a.dayofweek < 5

jan_to_mar = a.month.isin([0,1,2])
apr_to_oct = a.month.isin([3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
nov_to_dec = a.month.isin([10,11])

weekdays_in_jan_to_mar = a[weekday & jan_to_mar]
weekdays_in_apr_to_oct = a[weekday & apr_to_oct]
weekdays_in_nov_to_dec = a[weekday & nov_to_dec]

weekends = a[~weekday]
```

This later method could be generalized along the lines of `get_days()` to put the desired values in the call to `a.month.isin()` (or a.dayofweek.isin()).

```
DAYOFWEEK = dict(zip('mon tue wed thu fri sat sun'.split(), range(7)))
MONTH = dict(zip("jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec".split(), range(1, 13)))

def get_buckets(start, end, descriptions):
    dates = pd.date_range(start, end)
    buckets = []

    for description in descriptions:

        description = description.strip().lower().split('-')
        start = description[0][:3]
        end = start if len(description) == 1 else description[1][:3]

        if start in DAYOFWEEK:
            start = DAYOFWEEK[start]
            end = DAYOFWEEK[end]
            span = 0, len(DAYOFWEEK)
            selector = dates.dayofweek

        else:
            start = MONTH[start]
            end = MONTH[end]
            span = 1, len(MONTH) + 1
            selector = dates.month

        if start <= end:
            rng = set(range(start, end + 1))
        else:
            rng = set(range(*span)) - set(range(start - 1, end, - 1))

        buckets.append(dates[selector.isin(rng)])

    return buckets
```

By the way, the description of the problem implies that the buckets are mutually exclusive, but the code does not behave that way.  `get_dates()` and `usage()` will both put a date into multiple buckets